# Any way to get a File object from a JAR

Tags: java, file, io

I have a JAR file that contains an API that uses external model files.  I would like to include the model files in the JAR itself so it easier to use for other developers.  The API will accept a File object only, is there any way to do this?  I have already tried the following, and they have failed:

- Using class.getResourceAsStream().  This would work if the API accepted an InputStream.

  Parsing the classpath and trying to build from the entries (the JAR will show as app.jar)

I suppose an option is to use getResourceAsStream and move the files to a permanent location on the HDD but, I do not like this option.  There has to be something better, any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Resources in a .jar file are not files in the sense that the OS can access them directly via normal file access APIs.

And since `java.io.File` represents exactly that kind of file (i.e. a thing that looks like a file to the OS), it can't be used to refer to anything in a .jar file.

A possible workaround is to extract the resource to a temporary file and refer to that with a `File`.

Note that generally APIs that try to handle files should be written to handle `InputStream`/`OutputStream` as well to allow this kind of operations to suceed.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't write the API or else I would have done that.  I have already debated the temporary file solution and if that is the only option I'd rather use config files that other developers can set up where to put the files.