# Get RandomAccessFile from JAR archive

Tags: java, file, jar, bioinformatics

**Summary:**

I have a program I want to ship as a single `jar` file.

It depends on three big resource files (700MB each) in a binary format. The file content can easily be accessed via indexing, my parser therefore reads these files as `RandomAccessFile`-objects.

So my goal is to access resource files from a `jar` via `File` objects.

**My problem:**

When accessing the resource files from my file system, there is no issue, but I aim to pack them into the `jar` file of the program, so the user does not need to handle these files themselves.

The only way I found so far to access a file packed in a `jar` is via `InputStream` (generated by `class.getResourceAsStream()`), which is totally useless for my application as it would be much too slow reading these files from start to end instead of using `RandomAccessFile`.

Copying the file content into a file, reading it and deleting it in runtime is no option eigher for the same reason.

Can someone confirm that there is no way to achieve my goal or provide a solution (or a hint so I can work it out myself)?

**What I found so far:**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2192618/9568847) answer and if I understand the answer it says that there is no way to solve my problem:

> Resources in a .jar file are not files in the sense that the OS can access them directly via normal file access APIs.
>
> And since java.io.File represents exactly that kind of file (i.e. a thing that looks like a file to the OS), it can't be used to refer to anything in a .jar file.
>
> A possible workaround is to extract the resource to a temporary file and refer to that with a File.

I think I can follow the reasoning behind it, but it is over eight years old now and while I am not very educated when it comes to file systems and archives, I know that the Java language has evolved quite much since then, so maybe there is hope? :)

**Probably useless background information:**

The files are genomes in the `2bit` format and I use the `TwoBitParser` from `biojava` via the wrapper class `TwoBitFacade`?. The `Javadocs` can be found [here](http://biojava.org/docs/api/org/biojava/nbio/genome/parsers/twobit/TwoBitParser.html) and [here](http://biojava.org/docs/api/org/biojava/nbio/genome/parsers/twobit/TwoBitFacade.html).

Comment: 'So my goal is to access resource files from a jar via File objects.' So your goal is already a contradiction in terms. Resources are not files. They live in a JAR file, which is not a random access medium. Everything here is a self-contradiction.

Comment: Thanks @EJP, "Resources are not files. They live in a JAR file, which is not a random access medium." was exactly the information I needed. If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources are not files, and they live in a JAR file, which is not a random access medium.